# How can I find the selected XRControl (programmatically) in a XtraReport opened in the Report Designer (DevExpress)?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm struggling with finding selected/Clicked XRControl (programmatically) in an XtraReport when having it open in End-User Report Designer.
I would like to manipulate selected object but can't find any event to subscribe to.

Our environment are Report Designer and XtraReport, using WPF/xaml.

[XtraReport in DevExpress Report Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TSXK.jpg)

BR,
Chriss

Comment: this question needs more details if we are to help you - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that the question is a bit far-fetched, but hope for someone that have worked with DevExpress and encountered similar issue.